# Is it possible to get ESP8266 running on WPA2 Enterprise network?

Tags: c, arduino, esp8266

I've seen examples for ESP8266 chip Wifi clients logging onto a WPA2 personal network.

However, is it possible for an ESP8266 client to login to an *enterprise* network?

Answer (score 4):

Since Version 2.0 of the Espressif SDK, ESP8266 can be connected to both EAP and PEAP WPA2 Enterprise networks.

I quote [a small guide from GitHub](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1032#issuecomment-258907047) on how to implement the connection:

> 1. Call `wifi_station_set_config` to set the configuration of target AP.
> 2. Call `wifi_station_set_wpa2_enterprise_auth(1);` to enable WPA2_Enterprise authentication.
>
>    - For EAP-TLS authentication, call `wifi_station_set_enterprise_cert_key` to set certificate and private key. `wifi_station_set_enterprise_username` is an optional choice, it can be called to set user name.
>    - For EAP-TTLS or EAP-PEAP authentication, call `wifi_station_set_enterprise_username` and `wifi_station_set_enterprise_password` to set user name and password. `wifi_station_set_enterprise_ca_cert` is an optional choice, it can be called to set root certificate.
> 3. Call `wifi_station_connect` to connect to target AP.
> 4. After being connected to an AP, or failing to connect to AP and on stopped retries, please call the corresponding `wifi_station_clear_enterprise_XXX` APIs to release the resources.

Answer (score 2):

The feature was recently added and is not mature. It currently supports certificate (EAP-TLS) but not password (PEAP) authentication.

References:

- https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1102
- http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=46&t=1442

Comment: The newest version of the Espressif SDK now supports PEAP.